AG Grid filtering without an active AG Grid instance?
I've got my hands on a persisted ag-grid filter-model object, I have a set of rows that conform to it's expectation. But I don't actually have an ag-grid component anywhere on the page. Is there a way to filter my data headless? I do have the libraries available, I just don't need a table at the moment.
data + filter-model => ???? => filtered data

What do you mean by a filter-model? An example would help.

@PeterB https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filter-api/ result of the gridApi.getFilterModel() call. The documentation has an example of the json result
